# What is the name for the wall around the land

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

There is a wall
 around my land(Garden). What is the correct word to call it?

- parapet
- parapet wall
- rampart
- truss
- wall
- Any other

[image: Example:]

Comment: The name of the picture you link to is **garden_wall.jpg**. Might that be an option, as obviously _someone_ decided to call that thing by that name?

Comment: That is a textbook example of a **wall**.

Comment: "Wall" or "garden wall" sound right. Also possible: "boundary wall". "Parapets" are low, usually on roofs (or on other boundaries from where one can fall off), "Ramparts" are defensive structures, "trusses" are triangular supports. So none of those 3 apply to that picture.

Comment: You already called it a wall. Why isn't *wall* suitable?

Comment: It's simply the "garden wall."

Comment: The general confusion here is that you almost always refer to the .. dividing thing .. on such inner city lots as the "fence" - the garden fence, or simply the "fence" (what other "fence" could it be?)  But here it is brick, not, well, a fence. So you'd maybe say something like the "brick dividing wall" or even the "brick garden fence" to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd call that a *brick wall* (or, building on Frank's answer, a *brick perimeter wall).*

A perimeter wall can also be called a *boundary wall.*

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a **dividing wall**.

If it goes all the way round your property it could be a **perimeter wall**

Comment: Frank, I reckon 'perimeter wall' only works on a large property. That looks like a typical english "semi", you'd never refer to it as a "perimeter wall" - I like your "dividing wall" or just garden wall.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely looks like a compound wall. http://www.houzz.com/compound-wall reinforces my definition

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a "**privacy wall**" to me.

Answer (score 0):

*enclosure* is a special word for what you mean. OALD defines the word as a piece of
land surrounded by a fence or wall.

Comment: I've never seen 'enclosure' used in an 'encloser' sense.

Answer (score -2):

I would call that a **boundary of walls**.